# Ordered weighted averaging error QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, overlay

I am trying to use Ordered weighted averaging to sum up values across different raster overlays in QGIS 3.4.4, but I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.4/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\saga\SagaAlgorithm.py",
line 217, in processAlgorithm
files.append(parameters[param.name()].source()[:-4] + 'sgrd')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'source'
```

I have already tried to use Raster Calculator by SAGA, Raster analysis and GDAL, and GRASS' r.series, but either get an error or get a blank map. I have selected no-data value for 1 layer only, so I should get a result even if the areas don't overlap.

Answer (score 1):

At least in GRASS, the r.series module propagates NULLs only if you add the `-n` flag. But you should be aware that in GRASS you must set the computational region to cover **all** rasters.
So if you're trying to get the weighted average of rasters `rast1, rast2 rast3`, with weights 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, then:

```
RAST_LIST=`g.list rast pattern=rast*`
g.region -p input=$RAST_LIST 
r.series input=$RAST_LIST output=rast_avg weights=0.1,0.2,0.3
```